# What's the purpose of SetRegView lastused?

Tags: nsis

What's the purpose of `SetRegView lastused`?

The [docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#setregview) only talk about the 32/64 bit registry views, which I understand.

I thought it might be acting as a stack, like [this person](https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-278116.html), being able to switch back to the view before the one currently in use. But the response to someone asking that question was:

> No stack. Just the last one used.

In which case, if you're already in the 32 bit view, it's just equivalent to `SetRegView 32`? That doesn't seem right, what am I missing?

My google-fu only got me so far, finding this example from [Mozilla](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/installer/windows/nsis/maintenanceservice_installer.nsi) (snippet from full script):

```
; Since the Maintenance service can be installed either x86 or x64,
; always use the 64-bit registry.
${If} ${RunningX64}
    ; Previous versions always created the uninstall key in the 32-bit registry.
    ; Clean those old entries out if they still exist.
    SetRegView 32
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "${MaintUninstallKey}"
    ; Preserve the lastused value before we switch to 64.
    SetRegView lastused

    SetRegView 64
${EndIf}
```

Then in a couple places later in the script:

```
${If} ${RunningX64}
    SetRegView lastused
${EndIf}
```

Looking at the context there, if you call `SetRegView 32`, followed by `SetRegView lastused`, does that mean any future uses of `SetRegView lastused` will always result in the 32 bit registry view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not it is not a stack (but you could argue that it should be). It is simply the last set 32/64 state.

The `SetRegView` instruction is transformed into a NSIS opcode called `EW_SETFLAG` by MakeNSIS and its implementation in a installer looks something like this:

```
if (get_last_used)
  g_exec_flags[flag] = g_exec_flags_last_used[flag] ; Restore previous
else
  g_exec_flags_last_used[flag] = g_exec_flags[flag] ; Set last used
  g_exec_flags[flag] = new_value ; Assign new value
```

These flags are also available to plug-ins in the [exec_flags_t](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/NSIS/trunk/Source/exehead/api.h) struct.

It is only useful if you mainly deal with one registry view but once in a while need to read from the other view:

```
Section
SetRegView 64
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\Foo" "Bar"
SetRegView lastused ; We are now back to the default view (32-bit in this case)
SectionEnd
```

or if you mainly use the 64-bit view:

```
Function .onInit
SetRegView 64
FunctionEnd 

Section
SetRegView 32
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\Foo" "Bar"
SetRegView lastused ; We are now back to the previous view (64-bit in this case)
SectionEnd
```

I guess it is implemented this way because it simply reuses the lastused functionality used by other flags. It also simplifies things because it never has to allocate more memory. I also don't know why it is undocumented.